# latex does not use specified font

Tags: fonts

I have the latest full TeX-live installed. The following MWE does not select the font Droid Sans:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{droidsans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

On my PC, the output is the following:

[image: my output]

The correct output should look like this:

[image: correct output]

This is the compiler output: [compiler output](https://pastebin.com/7W1AEpzC), and this is the logfile: [logfile](https://pastebin.com/3yaYQE8h). I have already checked my `pdftex.map`, which seems to contain a section for droidsans: [pdftex.map](https://pastebin.com/Kgsftx3d).

How else can I debug this? What might be the cause for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `droidsans` by default only provides the `\fdsfamily` command to switch to Droid Sans, to use Droid Sans as the default font you have to pass the `default` option:

```
\usepackage[default]{droidsans}
```

If you prefer to keep your current (serif) default font, you can also use `defaultsans` instead of `default` to only change the default sans-serif font (The default sans-serif font is the font selected by `\textsf` and often used for headings etc.)

Generally it is always a good to look at [the package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/droid/doc/fonts/droid/droid.pdf) to find out how packages work, you can find it through the command line via `texdoc droidsans` or online at http://texdoc.net/